# Is it POSIX-compliant to use a shell function in a pipeline?

Tags: shell, sh, posix

Is it possible to use a shell function in a pipeline?

Say I had a function that acted like `grep`, called `mygrep`.
Is there any way, using only POSIX shell features, to be able to invoke
`mygrep` like this:

```
if ps | mygrep foo ; then
   echo "process foo is running"
fi
```

Or is piping limited to external commands only?

Comment: What keeps you from trying?

Comment: @KamilMaciorowski: Perhaps the uncertainity in whether it works due to being a standard POSIX feature, or whether it works due to being one of the million ksh/bash/zsh extensions. When OP mentions "using only ...", it's best to assume "Is it *supposed* to work?"

Comment: @grawity A reasonable guess, I get your point. If so, providing results of own tests in few shells would be a nice research effort.

Comment: @grawity My answer now addresses this issue. Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes. See [this document](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/contents.html).

[1. Introduction](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap01.html#tag_17)

> The Shell and Utilities volume of POSIX.1-2017 describes the commands and utilities offered to application programs by POSIX-conformant systems.

From [2.9.2 Pipelines](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_09_02):

> A pipeline is a sequence of one or more commands separated by the control operator '|'.

From [2.9.5 Function Definition Command](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_09_05):

> A function is a user-defined name that is used as a simple command [...]
>
> The format of a function definition command is as follows:
>
> ```
> fname ( ) compound-command [io-redirect ...]
> ```

From [2.9 Shell Commands](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_09):

> A command is one of the following:
>
> - Simple command [...]
> - [...]

So `|` separates commands; a command may be a simple command; function name is used as a simple command. The answer to your question is: yes, this syntax

```
some_command | some_function
```

is defined by POSIX.

---

It's quite easy to try (tested with `sh` provided by `dash` in Debian 9):

```
mygrep() { grep "$@"; }

if ps | mygrep foo ; then
   echo "process foo is running"
fi

if ps | mygrep ps ; then
   echo "process ps is running"
fi
```

(`ps | mygrep foo` will detect a process `foobar` as well, if any. I understand this issue is outside the scope of your question and we can ignore it).

In this example `mygrep` is trivial. It returns exit status of its last (and only) command. While building functions with more complex logic you may need special builtin `return` to return desired exit status.

Also note the output from `grep` is not suppressed. Not only a shell function can be used in pipes, its output can be redirected too. Example:

```
if ps | mygrep ps >/dev/null ; then
   echo "process ps is running"
fi
```

Comment: replaced with comment below.  SE was acting weird and it looked like my comment didn't get saved.

Comment: I'm embarrassed  that I didn't try this myself.  I thought that handling the stdin would be more involved, but in hindsight it seems obvious it just "goes" to the function (if that's the way to put it).  That you can redirect function output is also very interesting.  Thanks!

Answer (score -2):

You have to use oneliner form, or pack your expression to ${}. In that form you wrote as bash script it is not possible.

Comment: I don't really understand what you mean. Can you post an example? a working piece of code? As far as I know `${}` works with variables and makes things like `echo "${variable}_suffix"` possible.

Comment: just above example mygrep() { grep "$@"; }